# How do I explicitly print the labels for a given equation?

Tags: equations

I am using `mathtools`, only `refeq` equations get actually a number.

However, there are several equations which I want to have the equation numbering appear on the right, or more accurately, decide on my own where they would appear.

Is there a way to do that, so that I add the equation numbering the place I want them for a certain align environment, *but* also so that when I refer to them using `refeq`, they won't appear on the left side?

EDIT, MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage,times,color,hyperref}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{qtree}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
aaa \label{eq1}
\end{align}

(Look at equation ~\refeq{eq1}.)

I would want it to look more like:

\begin{align}
(1)\,\,\,\,\, & aaa
\end{align}

only it should be far to the left, and only for a *single* align environment (or a few).

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could pass to the class, the option [leqno] if you'd like to consistently number them on the left. In my humble opinion, changing the numbering side abruptly would be very bad typography.

Comment: The point of an equation number is that the equation can easily be referenced. Unless the document should not be read by others, the readers might want to reference some equations (they might have a question, found an error, want to cite, ...). Since at the time of writing it is not known which equations might be referenced by future readers, all equations should be numbered. Also I think, it might more confuse than helpful for the readers if the equations numbers are randomly at the left and the right side.

Comment: I have to (almost completely) agree with Heiko here. Did you manage to solve the issue yourself and can provide a self answer, even if it would be bad style?